# search for a pattern "=[char][string]" using awk in a file

Tags: bash

I'm using awk and I simplly want to match the following : "=string" and NOT "= string", for example say I have a file like this:

```
    mike =string
    mike = string
    mike = string
    mike =string
    mike = string
```

I want the following as output:

```
    mike =string
    mike =string
```

Note:  string is the password field so it can be anything  mike =[[:alum:]]...

For some reason I can't figure this out!!! Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE: THE ANSWER:**

```
    awk '/=[[:alnum:]]/' file
```

Because I am looking for improper lines in AIX passwd files that do not have a space after '=' sign.  I need to print the lines for that user like this:

```
    awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/password =[[:alnum:]]/' shadow.aix
```

Comment: What have you tried already? What is your current attempt? Is 'mike = string' two fields or three? If two how are they split? Are there other fields in the input?

Comment: `awk` is suitable for column oriented files, why not use `grep` or `sed`?

Comment: Thanks for responding,  this worked:  awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/password =[[:alnum:]]/' shadow.aix  (i'm trying to print lines of a shadow file, made some mistakes with regex. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk '/=[[:alnum:]]/' file
```

or this `grep` will work too:

```
grep '=[[:alnum:]]' file
```

**Update:** As per your updated question you can use this awk:

```
awk -F ' *= *' -v OFS=' =' '{print $1, $2}' file
mike =string
mike =string
mike =string
mike =string
mike =string
```

Comment: Thanks,   basically I was trying to print out lines of an AIX 'shadow' file:   awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/password =[[:alnum:]]/' shadow.aix